# Query for All Invoices With Open Balances using QuickBooks Online (QBO) Intuit Partner Platform (IPP) DevKit

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, devkit

I am trying to Query for all invoices with open balances using IPP but I keep on getting 0 results back.  Am I doing something wrong in code?

Here is my C# code snippet that I am trying to do with the applied Filtering

```
        InvoiceQuery qboInvoiceQuery = new InvoiceQuery();
        int iMaxPageNumber = QUERY_MAX_PAGE_NUMBER;   // A Constant with the Maximum Page Number allowed in a query 
        int iResultsPerPage = QUERY_MAX_NUM_PER_PAGE_INVOICE; // A Constant with the Maximum Results per page 

        // Paging Information
        qboInvoiceQuery.PageNumber = QUERY_START_PAGE_NUMBER;
        qboInvoiceQuery.ResultsPerPage = iResultsPerPage;

        #region Query Filtering
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        //   initial filtering via Query Criteria   //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Get only Open (Unpaid) Invoices
        qboInvoiceQuery.OpenBalance = (decimal)0.00;
        qboInvoiceQuery.SpecifyOperatorOption(FilterProperty.OpenBalance, FilterOperatorType.AFTER);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        // END initial filtering via Query Criteria //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        #endregion

        // Complete the Query calls to build the list
        IEnumerable<Invoice> results = qboInvoiceQuery.ExecuteQuery<Invoice>(_ServiceContext);
        IEnumerable<Invoice> qboInvoices = results;
        int iCount = results.Count();
        while (iCount > 0 && iCount == iResultsPerPage && qboInvoiceQuery.PageNumber <= iMaxPageNumber)
        {
            qboInvoiceQuery.PageNumber++;
            results = qboInvoiceQuery.ExecuteQuery<Invoice>(_ServiceContext);
            iCount = results.Count();
            qboInvoices = qboInvoices.Concat(results);
        }
```

*** **UPDATE** ***

I have implemented peterl's answer and now have the following code.  However I am now running into a new problem that my code is always returning the default of 10 invoices and is not taking into consideration my body.  Even if i set it to a different page number or ResultsPerPage value I was get back the first page and 10 results.  Any ideas?

```
    private Dictionary<string, Invoice> GetUnpaidInvoicesDictionary(IdType CustomerId, bool bById = true)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Invoice> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Invoice>();
        int iMaxPageNumber = 100;
        int iResultsPerPage = 100;

        try
        {
            OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
            {
                ConsumerKey = _sConsumerKey,
                SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
                ConsumerSecret = _sConsumerSecret
            };

            string sBaseURL = "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1";
            string sUrlRequestToken = "/get_request_token";
            string sUrlAccessToken = "/get_access_token";
            OAuthSession oSession = new OAuthSession(consumerContext, 
                                                        sBaseURL + sUrlRequestToken,
                                                        sBaseURL,
                                                        sBaseURL + sUrlAccessToken);

            oSession.AccessToken = new TokenBase
            {
                Token = _sAccessToken,
                ConsumerKey = _sConsumerKey,
                TokenSecret = _sAccessTokenSecret
            };

            int iPageNumber = QUERY_START_PAGE_NUMBER;
            string sCustomerId = CustomerId.Value;
            string sBodyBase = "PageNum={0}&ResultsPerPage={1}&Filter=OpenBalance :GreaterThan: 0.00 :AND: CustomerId :EQUALS: {2}";
            string sBody = String.Format(sBodyBase, iPageNumber, iResultsPerPage, sCustomerId);

            IConsumerRequest conReq = oSession.Request();
            conReq = conReq.Post().WithRawContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").WithRawContent(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sBody)); ;
            conReq = conReq.ForUrl(_DataService.ServiceContext.BaseUrl + "invoices/v2/" + _DataService.ServiceContext.RealmId);
            conReq = conReq.SignWithToken();



            // Complete the Query calls to build the list
            SearchResults searchResults = (SearchResults)_DataService.ServiceContext.Serializer.Deserialize<SearchResults>(conReq.ReadBody());
            IEnumerable<Invoice> results = ((Invoices)searchResults.CdmCollections).Invoice;
            IEnumerable<Invoice> qboInvoices = results;
            int iCount = searchResults.Count;
            while (iCount > 0 && iCount == iResultsPerPage && iPageNumber <= iMaxPageNumber)
            {
                iPageNumber++;

                sBody = String.Format(sBodyBase, iPageNumber, iResultsPerPage, sCustomerId);
                conReq = oSession.Request();
                conReq = conReq.Post().WithRawContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").WithRawContent(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sBody)); ;
                conReq = conReq.ForUrl(_DataService.ServiceContext.BaseUrl + "invoices/v2/" + _DataService.ServiceContext.RealmId);
                conReq = conReq.SignWithToken();

                searchResults = (SearchResults)_DataService.ServiceContext.Serializer.Deserialize<SearchResults>(conReq.ReadBody());
                results = ((Invoices)searchResults.CdmCollections).Invoice;
                qboInvoices = qboInvoices.Concat(results);
                iCount = searchResults.Count;
            }

            if (bById)
                foreach (Invoice Inv in qboInvoices)
                    dictionary.Add(Inv.Id.Value, Inv);
            else
                foreach (Invoice Inv in qboInvoices)
                    dictionary.Add(Inv.Header.DocNumber, Inv);

            return dictionary;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

*** UPDATE ***

There is a similar issue out there that involves the new api tester.  This could be related to this issue and they are currently looking into it.

[Stack Overflow: QuickBooks Online querying with filter returns 401 everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695065/quickbooks-online-querying-with-filter-returns-401-everytime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the DevKit.  The OpenBalance filter defaults to :EQUALS: and does not support :GreaterThan:.

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/Invoice#Attributes_Supporting_Filtering_and_Sorting

Here is a workaround using DevDefined to construct the OAuth header:

```
public List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Invoice> GetQboUnpaidInvoices(DataServices dataServices, int startPage, int resultsPerPage,  IdType CustomerId)
{
    StringBuilder requestXML = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder responseXML = new StringBuilder();

    var requestBody = String.Format("PageNum={0}&ResultsPerPage={1}&Filter=OpenBalance :GreaterThan: 0.00 :AND: CustomerId :EQUALS: {2}", startPage, resultsPerPage, CustomerId.Value);

    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(dataServices.ServiceContext.BaseUrl + "invoices/v2/" + dataServices.ServiceContext.RealmId) as HttpWebRequest;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetDevDefinedOAuthHeader(httpWebRequest, requestBody));
    requestXML.Append(requestBody);
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] content = encoding.GetBytes(requestXML.ToString());
    using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
    }
    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    using (Stream data = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SearchResults searchResults = (Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SearchResults)dataServices.ServiceContext.Serializer.Deserialize<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SearchResults>(new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd());
        return ((Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Invoices)searchResults.CdmCollections).Invoice.ToList();
    }

}

protected string GetDevDefinedOAuthHeader(HttpWebRequest webRequest, string requestBody)
{

    OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
    {
        ConsumerKey = consumerKey,
        ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret,
        SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true

    };

    consumerContext.UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true;

    //URIs not used - we already have Oauth tokens
    OAuthSession oSession = new OAuthSession(consumerContext, "https://www.example.com",
                            "https://www.example.com",
                            "https://www.example.com");


    oSession.AccessToken = new TokenBase
    {
        Token = accessToken,
        ConsumerKey = consumerKey,
        TokenSecret = accessTokenSecret
    };

    IConsumerRequest consumerRequest = oSession.Request();
    consumerRequest = ConsumerRequestExtensions.ForMethod(consumerRequest, webRequest.Method);
    consumerRequest = ConsumerRequestExtensions.ForUri(consumerRequest, webRequest.RequestUri);
    if (webRequest.Headers.Count > 0)
    {
        ConsumerRequestExtensions.AlterContext(consumerRequest, context => context.Headers = webRequest.Headers);
        if (webRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> formParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (string formParameter in requestBody.Split('&'))
            {
                formParameters.Add(formParameter.Split('=')[0], formParameter.Split('=')[1]);
            }
            consumerRequest = consumerRequest.WithFormParameters(formParameters);
        }
    }

    consumerRequest = consumerRequest.SignWithToken();
    return consumerRequest.Context.GenerateOAuthParametersForHeader();
}
```

http://nuget.org/packages/DevDefined.OAuth

Comment: Thank you, your code has really helped to start getting the solution.  I am now having unexpected results of it not taking into account, filtering, results per page, page number, ect.  I have updated my question above if you wanted to take a shot at it.  Thank you.

Comment: Please try http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7VUB6whp and make sure you are using the latest version of DevDefined from NuGet.  Your code above (and maybe my original example) sends the OAuth authentication in the body of the request, without any other fields, rather than the header.  So, the service is returning the default response of page 1 with 10 records.

Comment: I believe the issue may be the version of DevDefined in the sample code above.  I updated it to the latest.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I will attempt this later today after we do our build.