# Intuit Partner Platform (IPP) QuickBooks Online (QBO) BlueDot Menu ASPX page not rendering in Internet Explorer (IE)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, infragistics, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have an .aspx page to display either the BlueDot or ConnectToQuickBooks buttons.
The resultant HTML looks like this, as collected from the IE page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>TrueCommerce to Intuit Connect Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
            menuProxy: 'http://localhost:1384/MenuProxy.aspx',
            grantUrl: 'http://localhost:1384/OauthGrant.aspx'
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="blueDotDiv">
    <ipp:bluedot></ipp:bluedot>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code will not display in IE.  It will display fine in Chrome and Firefox.

I validated the HTML with [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) and only received an error on the  tag, which was to be expected.

I am using the following IE Browser 
**IE Version:** 8.0.7601.17514   64-bit Edition

We are using Silverlight and have embedded the ASPX page utilizing the [Infragistics HTML Viewer Control - Silverlight xamHtmlViewer](http://www.infragistics.com/products/silverlight/html-viewer/).  The BlueDot Menu does not appear when called from either inside of the xamHtmlViewer or called directly (though it works both ways in Chrome and Firefox).

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0060_Reference/Widgets/0010_Connect_Button

To display the Connect to QuickBooks button in IE8, the html xmlns attribute is required, for example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ipp="">
```

Comment: Thank you very much peterl.  That was my issue.  I updated all of my aspx pages.

Comment: Since I have your attention right now, could you possibly look back at one of my previous issues. I am still having issues with [Selecting All Unpaid Invoices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323815/query-for-all-invoices-with-open-balances-using-quickbooks-online-qbo-intuit-p)  Thank you in advance.